# Unable to get Owners for groups using Microsoft graph

Tags: graph, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I am able to get the Owner collection for a Office 365 group using Graph.
But the same query is not able to get me the Owners for Security enabled and Distribution lists.

Is it a limitation that Graph only works well with Office 365 groups and I am struggling to get for non O365 groups.

I am implementing azure app registration to communicate with groups via graph.

Answer (score 0):

It should works. Please check the request below:
[image]

Did you get any error or have the owner for the group?

Comment: No this doenst work. It is determined that the EXO attribute for managedBy is not necessarily the Owner of the group, hence this mapping doesn’t exist.

However I would think that the Owner in Exchange should sync to AAD as the owner. If this does, then we could look to copy the managedBy data and populate it into the Owner attribute in EXO via powershell.
Then the data would be extractable via MS Graph as it should sync into AAD.

.